# Function in my plugin is called twice

Tags: plugins, functions

I have created a plugin. I added it to a wordpress page with following action:

```
add_shortcode("myplugin", "MyFunction");
```

I am posting some information via form/POST to this plugin. Unfortunately one important function (calling external URL/API via CURL) is processed twice every time I am posting this information.

Do you have any idea why/how to avoid this?

Comment: Can you provide some additional information on how your fundtion is actually called, when you are 'posting information* …?

Comment: A sample/simplified code of 'MyFunction' will also be helpful.

Comment: Find a short version below. I try to analyze the GET-/POST-information and switch to subfunctions after that. 
function1() seem to be called twice. 

`function MyFunction($atts) {

          $content = "Content...";
          // [...]
    // switching tasks by GET/POST-parameters
    switch ($task) {
           case "task1":
            $content = function1($value1, $value2);
            break;
          default: 
            $content = showform();
          }
    
    return $content;
}`

Comment: I figured out that the problem is cause by one plugin: "Simple Facebook Connect". With deactivated plugin there is no duplicate call of function. Strange. Any ideas for this?